# Java - LL of Queues Implementation Duplicates Queue for each LL Node

Tags: java, linked-list, queue, radix-sort

I am trying to program an example of a RadixSort in Java, and while I understand how the algorithm works I am running into a few issues with my implementation of a Linked List of Queues.

I believe my issue is when when I update the linked list at the nth position with a new Queue as it's value.  I believe I am using the same Queue for each nodes update and that is causing me to get the same values for every node in my linked list.

So when starting with an array of `int[] theArray = {4,3,5,9,7,2,4,1,6,5};`

I end up with a linked list of 10 nodes each consisting a queue of:`{4,3,5,9,7,2,4,1,6,5}`

I thought by using the `new` keyword it would create a fresh instance but it seems to be carrying over the old values each iteration.

Can someone either explain or point me in the right direction to understanding why this is happening?

EDIT: (Forgot to attach code)

```
package radixsort;
import java.util.*;
/**
 * @author dlanz
 */
public class RadixSort {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int[] theArray = {4,3,5,9,7,2,4,1,6,5};

        RadixSort theSort = new RadixSort();

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theArray)); //Outputs the original array
        theSort.sort(theArray);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(theArray)); //Outputs the original array (no modifictions)
    }



    public void sort(int[] theArray) {
        int significant;
        int curVal;    
        int modulo = 10;
        int ofInterest = 1;

        LinkedList<Queue> lists = new LinkedList<>();
        Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        int max = theArray[0];
        for(int i = 0; i < theArray.length; i++) {
            if ( theArray[i] > max) {
                  max = theArray[i];
            }
        }
        significant = String.valueOf(max).length();
        Queue<Integer> thisQueue;
        for(int j = 1; j <= significant; j++){

            lists.clear();
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                lists.add(i, queue);
            }
            System.out.println(lists); //Outputs a list of 10 elements each with a value of null
            for(int value : theArray){
                  curVal = value % modulo;
                  curVal = curVal / ofInterest;
                  System.out.println(curVal); //Correctly outputs the expected result
                  System.out.println(lists.get(curVal)); //With each iteration this outputs 10 elements each with a queue of all values.

                  thisQueue = new LinkedList<>();
                  thisQueue = lists.get(curVal);
                  thisQueue.add(value);

                  lists.set(curVal, thisQueue);// This seems to insert the generated queue into every linked lists node.
            }
            int k = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
                Queue<Integer> curQueue = lists.get(i);
                if(!curQueue.isEmpty()){
                    theArray[k] = curQueue.remove();
                    k++;
                }
            }
            ofInterest = ofInterest * 10;
            modulo = modulo * 10;
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT 2:

I've been playing around with it, and it seems as if `thisQueue`, `lists` and `queue` are shared.  When I perform certain actions on `thisQueue` such as `thisQueue.add(1)`, the value of '1' is added across the board.  If I do the same on `lists` with `lists.add(1)` every node in `lists` is populated with the value 1.

I remember reading something about object values being passed by reference (not the objects themselves though), can this have any thing to do with what I am experiencing?

Edit 3:

I've also noticed that if I use literals instead of variables in the `.add()` lines such as

```
thisQueue.add(value);
```

The values do not duplicate as mentioned in EDIT 2.  I tried to cast the variables used as `int` even though they were declared as Int, but still got the same results.

Comment: I suppose I will post a less specific question.  I will put together some code recreating the issue but not with all of this extra "Radix Sort" stuff.  When I post the new question I will provide a link on here to redirect anyone in the future with a similar question.

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I appreciate how no one responded to this question.  I figured it out on my own while creating a set of sample code and formulating a less specific question.  But I will not forget this, for a very long time.

What was happening was in the portion of code where I loop through and create nodes 0-9 in my Linked List

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    lists.add(i, queue);
}
```

I was adding a reference to the very same Queue.  So regardless of the use of the other Queues/.clear() I was essentially pulling the reference to that original Queue on this line

```
thisQueue = lists.get(curVal);
```

While I made a few changes along the way, all that really had to be done was change the loop to

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    queue = new LinkedList<>();
    lists.add(i, queue);
}
```

and change

```
Queue<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();
```

To just

```
Queue<Integer> queue
```

I had thought of explicitly creating 10 Separate Queues and then using a switch in the code to decide which queue should be used.  This did not seem very flexible and would have been very tedious.  At the same time I realized that creating a new Queue for each iteration is very costly.  I would be creating as many objects as are in the array, in this case 10, but that could be 100, 1000, 1000000.  By using (correct me if I'm wrong) anonymous objects I was able to create only as many objects as needed (1 for each element in the linked lists).